# Accessing an HTTP Server on a Private Subnet via a Public Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services

On AWS, I have an EC2 instance with an HTTP server running on port 8888 inside a private subnet, and an EC2 instance that can communicate with it in a public subnet. How can I access the HTTP server running inside the private subnet via the public subnet? I understand that I can use the public EC2 instance as a proxy server via an SSH tunnel, but I am unable to access the server from my browser.

This is the command I am running on the public server:

`ssh -R 0.0.0.0:8888:localhost:8888 -N user@private_server`

When I access `public_server:8888` on my browser, I am unable to connect. I may need to set up the browser to access traffic through a proxy server (via some chrome extension) but this is not what I want. Is there a way to set up the public server such that no work needs to be done by the client to access the server via their browser?

Comment: Create a NAT Gateway (prefer a managed one) and configure the route from the priv subnet to go thru that natgw. Or just put the HTTP server on a public subnet.

Comment: I'll try the NAT gateway, good idea. Unfortunately, I can't put the HTTP server on a public subnet, due to company info security policy (if I try it automatically gets killed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research, and realized I was looking for a reverse proxy, and could just simplify further by using an Application Load Balancer running in the public subnet that could interface with the instance running in the private subnet.